# Calculating an angle between 2 vectors given their value and the value of their sum

Tags: vectors

Given the value of 2 vectors A and B, and the value of the resultant vector C, how would I go about calculating the angle between A and B?

Thanks a lot

Comment: $\cos \theta = \dfrac{A\cdot B}{|A|||B|}$ ? Since you already know $A$ and $B$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By value, I assume you mean *magnitude* and **direction**. Thus, you should be able to calculate the angle between them: $\theta_a = cos^{-1}(\frac{\vec{A}_x}{\vec{A}})$ and $\theta_b = cos^{-1}(\frac{\vec{B}_x}{\vec{B}})$. Now perform subtraction on $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$, and find its absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

As $A,B,C$ are the sides of a triangle, you can just apply e.g. the law of cosines

$$C^2=A^2+B^2-2AB\cos(\gamma)$$ and solve for $\gamma$. Then the angle between them is obviously the supplement angle $\phi = \pi-\gamma$.

[image: adding vectors]